# How to relate user table with a another table

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm not sure how to ask this question so i couldn't actually google it, but im sure there is an easy answer to this.

I have a Table with users on it and another tables with X amount of rows. what i am looking for is to be able to relate any user to x amount of the rows. At the same time the Rows can have many users related to it, it's both ways

Comment: What you're looking for is called a "foreign key".

Comment: and you will need a foreign key as @David said

Comment: @SaggingRufus its kind of obvious the join part, what i was asking is how to make the join, ill look into what foreign key is

Comment: how is the join obvious, but not the foreign key?! you need foreign keys to have joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a "foreign key" on the other table.  Let's say you have a `Users` table:

```
Users
----------
ID (int, PK)
Name (varchar)
etc.
```

Then in your other table you would have a column which points back to this table:

```
Widgets
----------
ID (int, PK)
UserID (int, FK) <-- this is the foreign key
etc.
```

The syntax of how you create that foreign key relationship would depend on the database you're using, it'll be in the documentation.  There are a variety of options for such a foreign key, but the main thing is that it maintains relational integrity in the data.  So if you try to insert a record into `Widgets` with an invalid `UserID` then it will throw an error, because there must be a matching `ID` in `Users` to relate the data.

Once this relationship is in place, querying the data is simple:

```
SELECT * FROM Users
INNER JOIN Widgets
  ON Users.ID = Widgets.UserID
```

---

**Edit:** Based on the comment below, it sounds like you're looking for a "many to many" relationship.  Same concept, all you need is an intermediate table to connect them.  Something like this:

```
Users
----------
ID (int, PK)
Name (varchar)
etc.

Widgets
----------
ID (int, PK)
etc.

UserWidgets
----------
ID (int, PK) <-- optional, the PK could be a composite of the FKs
UserID (int, FK)
WidgetID (int, FK)
```

Now any User and any Widget can be connected to any number of the other, by way of adding more records to the `UserWidgets` table.  That table holds the relationships themselves, since those relationships are also data.

Querying is just another join:

```
SELECT * FROM Users
INNER JOIN UserWidgets
  ON Users.ID = UserWidgets.UserID
INNER JOIN Widgets
  ON UserWidgets.WidgetID = Widgets.ID
```

Comment: yes, but a widget might be related to more than 1 user, how could i achieve this?

Comment: @pato.llaguno: That's different from what was specified.  What exactly is this relationship?  Can a User have many Widgets and a Widget have many Users?

Comment: @pato.llaguno: That's just a "many to many" relationship, all it requires is an additional table to hold the relationship itself.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially talking about Normalization and you can use a foreign key constraint here to resolve such relationship.

For e.g 
In case of EMP (MANY) and DEPT ( ONE) [ One department has many employees ], you would put a DEPT_ID ( that identifies a department row in DEPT table) as a Foreign key in EMP table.

You could apply similar solution to your use case.